# php is running in terminal, but not in browser

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm using Mac OS El Captain, Apache/2.4.23 (Unix), PHP 5.6.27 (cli)

I've reinstalled Apache and PHP with brew

```
brew reinstall httpd24 --with-privileged-ports --with-http2
brew reinstall php56 --with-apache
```

There was a message:

To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:

```
   LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I did it, as was said

And now I can run php files in terminal from command line,
but can't run php in browser

```
localhost/test1.php
```

where test1.php contains:

```
    <?php
    phpinfo(); 
    ?>
```

In Apache localhost classical  - "It works" was shown, so it really worked, but without php

Comment: post your apache error log   which default in /var/log/httpd/

Comment: "It works" is just Apache's default index page. It doesn't have anything to do with PHP. You need to configure your own site (whether you want to use PHP or not), maybe using name based virtual hosts.

Comment: @chenyb999 there is no entries in error_log which can correspond with access_log entry     ::1 - - [08/Nov/2016:08:24:43 +0300] "GET /test1.php HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [08/Nov/2016:08:25:02 +0300] "-" 408 -
::1 - - [08/Nov/2016:08:25:30 +0300] "GET /test1.php HTTP/1.1" 200 232
::1 - - [08/Nov/2016:08:25:50 +0300] "-" 408 -

Comment: I'm not family with macos,in centos, i'll check:
1. try: 127.0.0.1/test1.php
2. check the access right of test1.php . is this file accessed by apache?
3. check the firewall settings;
3. are there something like SELinux in MacOS? turn it off.

Comment: @chenyb999 I just uninstall apache and php and install mamp. now it works.